# Newtonsoft exception throws, "Input string '08' is not a valid number"

Tags: c#, firebase

I am trying to make a basic c# code copied from the web (http://scriptopia.co.uk/Post.php?id=8) so as to familiarize myself with firebase. The code seems to work fine by sending the Time data to the database except for the 8th second. Can someone tell me why this strange behavior?

```
        while (true)
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            string hour = date.ToString("HH");
            string minutes = date.ToString("mm");
            string seconds = date.ToString("ss");

            string jsondata = "{'Time':{'Hour':  " + hour + ",'Minute':  " + minutes + ", 'Second':  " + seconds + ", }}";
            JObject data = JObject.Parse(jsondata);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);


            var request = System.Net.WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://******.firebaseio.com/.json?auth=***db**secret***");
            request.Method = "PATCH";
            request.ContentType = "json";
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            json = (new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
        }
```

I was hoping to receive continuous time data without any error, however in this case at the 8th second of every minute the code crashes. I tried running it in an online compiler and observed the same results.

Comment: BTW, `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` is supposed to be the reverse operation of `JObject.Parse`.  If you produced proper JSON in the first place, you wouldn't need either one (you could just do `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsondata)` directly)

Answer (score 2):

When you get the seconds, format it with just "s" so that it doesn't have a leading zero: `string seconds = date.ToString("s");` and do the same with the hours and minutes.

Comment: This might be a stupid question but then why am I getting error at 08th second? Shouldn't there be an error the moment it reaches 00?

Comment: That is not a stupid question. The reason is that in json a number with a leading zero is treated as octal, so only the digits 0 to 7 are allowed, so 07 is a legal number, the following one would be 010

Comment: @iakobski: This isn't JSON behavior.  It's Newtonsoft Json library behavior.  In standard JSON, leading zeros are not permitted at all.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @BenVoigt. I should have written "The reason is that in the transformation to json..."

Answer (score -2):

if json value is like this =>

```
{
    "Data" : "Value"
}
```

it means type of "Data" is String.

Change it as

```
{
    "Data" : value
}
```

then it'll be int value.